# Angular pass service with dependencies to module using forRoot

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have a service for authentication based on JWT. To reuse this service in all my projects i created a library which should be shipped with npm.

For this service to work i need some API-Calls. In every project the API could look completely different so i don't want to provide this functionality inside my library instead inject another service which handles my API-Calls.

My idea was to create a module which contains my service and provide an interface to describe the service for API-Calls and inject it forRoot. The Problem is that my api service has some dependencies like HttpClient and i cannot simple instantiate it in my app.module.

My library looks like:

***auth.module.ts***

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { AuthAPI } from '../models/authAPI';
import { AuthapiConfigService } from '../services/authapi-config.service';


@NgModule()
export class AuthModule {

  static forRoot(apiService: AuthAPI): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: AuthModule,
      providers: [
        AuthService,
        {
          provide: AuthapiConfigService,
          useValue: apiService
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

***auth-api.interface.ts***

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface AuthAPI {
  reqLogin(): Observable<{ access_token: string; }>;
  reqRegister(): Observable<{ access_token: string; }>;
}
```

***auth-api-config.service.ts***

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthAPI } from '../models/authAPI';
/**
 * This is not a real service, but it looks like it from the outside.
 * It's just an InjectionTToken used to import the config object, provided from the outside
 */
export const AuthapiConfigService = new InjectionToken<AuthAPI>('API-Service');
```

***auth.service.ts***

```
 constructor(@Inject(AuthapiConfigService) private apiService) {}
```

How i am trying to implement it:

***auth-rest-service.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthAPI } from 'projects/library-project/src/lib/auth/models/authAPI';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthRestService implements AuthAPI  {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  reqLogin(): Observable<{ access_token: string; }> {
    return this.http.post<{access_token: string}>(`/login`, 'test');
  }

  reqRegister(): Observable<{ access_token: string; }> {
    return this.http.post<{access_token: string}>(`/login`, 'test');
  }

}
```

***app.module.ts***

```
import { AuthRestService } from './components/auth-service/auth-rest.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    AuthModule.forRoot(AuthRestService),
    ...
  ],
  providers: [AuthModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I can't create an instance of AuthRestService because of the dependencies this service has (HttpClient). Is there any method to tell angular to provide me this service.

Comment: Did you manage to accomplish this?

Comment: I found that "forRoot" wasn't the right way to do it. You need to provide the config service inside the module. But after working around so many problems my need wasn't that big enough, so i never finished this idea. Another idea i had was to ship the service within the module and pass callbacks as params to the methods with the logic i want to execute. Mabye that helps you thinking it further.

Answer (score 5):

This is possible with usage of angular's `Injector`.

```
import { Injector, ModuleWithProviders, NgModule, Optional, Provider, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { isFunction } from 'lodash';

export function resolveService(cfg: SharedConfig, inj: Injector): IncompleteService {
  const provider = cfg?.service;
  // if service is an angular provider, use Injector, otherwise return service instance as simple value
  const service = isFunction(service) ? inj.get(provider) : provider;
  return service;
}

/**
 * Service to be implemented from outside the module.
 */
@Injectable()
export abstract class IncompleteService {
  abstract strategyMethod();
}

// Optional: A config object is optional of course, but usually it fits the needs.
export interface SharedConfig {
  service: IncompleteService | Type<IncompleteService> | InjectionToken<IncompleteService>;
  // other config properties...
}

/*
 * Optional: If a Config interface is used, one might resolve the config itself 
 * using other dependencies (e.g. load JSON via HTTPClient). Hence an InjectionToken 
 * is necessary.
 */
export const SHARED_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<SharedConfig>('shared-config');

// Optional: If SharedConfig is resolved with dependencies, it must be provided itself.  
export type ModuleConfigProvider = ValueProvider | ClassProvider | ExistingProvider | FactoryProvider;

/**
 * One can provide the config as is, i.e. "{ service: MyService }" or resolved by 
 * injection, i.e.
 * { provide: SHARED_CONFIG: useFactory: myConfigFactory, deps: [DependentService1, DependentService2] }
 */
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: []
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(config: SharedConfig | ModuleConfigProvider): ModuleWithProviders<SharedModule> {
    // dynamic (config is Provider) or simple (config is SharedConfig)
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
        (config as ModuleConfigProvider).provide ? (config as Provider) : { provide: SHARED_CONFIG, useValue: config },
        { provide: IncompleteService, useFactory: resolveService, deps: [SHARED_CONFIG, Injector] },
        // ... provide additional things
      ],
    };
}


/**
 * In general not really useful, because usually an instance of IncompleteService
 * need other dependencies itself. Hence you cannot provide this instance without
 * creating it properly. But for the sake of completeness, it should work as well.
 */
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: []
})
export class MostSimpleSharedModule {
  static forRoot(service: IncompleteService): ModuleWithProviders<SharedModule> {
    // dynamic (config is Provider) or simple (config is SharedConfig)
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: IncompleteService, useValue: service },
        // ... provide additional things
      ],
    };
}
```

**EDIT**

If you really need an interface iso. an (injectable) abstract class `IncompleteService`, you just need to define another `InjectionToken<IncompleteServiceInterface>` and provide this token explicitly.

Comment: Looks good! I will test it later on and mark your answer as accept if this works. Thanks for answering such an old question :)